# Rider cannot publish .NET web application on a Mac

Tags: rider

I am trying to deploy a simple solution with a single project in it on Rider for Mac. Even just deploying a new default project won't work (build does work, and local debug also works fine).

I am getting the error

```
05:43:28 Building /Users/danielcamps/RiderProjects/ApiSolution/ApiProject/ApiProject.csproj
  Target _DeploymentUnpublishable:
    Skipping unpublishable project.
  Target ValidateSolutionConfiguration:
    Building solution configuration "Debug|Any CPU".
Publish succeeded at 17:43:28
```

I saw somewhere that the MSBuild version could be a factor, but changing that from Auto Detected (15.0) to a different one (12.0) results in a different error:

```
  ApiProject.csproj: [null] /Users/danielcamps/RiderProjects/ApiSolution/ApiProject/ApiProject.csproj: error : Target named 'Publish' not found in the project.
```

I am stuck, does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You couldn't publish classic web app on Mac because Mono MSBuild targets don't support it.